# MySQL Longitude Latitude not accurate

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to select all records nearby based on longitude and latitude.

The problem is it's not accurate, e.g. this query says a user is 42km away when it's actually 65km away.

I've taken the lon and lat values put them in a php script which calculates the distance property which means the query is incorrect.

Any ideas on why it's out so much?

```
    SELECT
        id,
        first_name,
        (6371 * acos (
           cos ( radians(latitude) )
           * cos( radians( LAT ) )
           * cos( radians( LON ) - radians(longitude) )
           + sin ( radians(latitude) )
           * sin( radians( LAT ) )
          )
        ) AS distance
    FROM
        users
```

PHP Code that works

```
$dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($lon1 - $lon2));
$dist = acos($dist);
$dist = rad2deg($dist);
$miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
$unit = strtoupper($unit);

if ($unit == "K") {
    return ($miles * 1.609344);
} else if ($unit == "N") {
    return ($miles * 0.8684);
} else {
    return $miles;
}
```

Comment: How does the PHP script compute the distance? Is it haversine as well or road distance ?

Comment: @ArunNalla It's just a basic script that found on the internet and it works fine, I remade the formula in MySQL and didn't work, was still out.

Comment: Specify datatype for all 4 parameters used in the calculation for MySQL code. And compare with the same in PHP code.

Comment: All parameters are identical, i recreated the query looks like when the query runs as a stored procedure it doesn't work properly :/

Comment: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I would observe that 65/42 = 1.54, which is pretty close to 1.6 - a number which appears in one formula, and not the other.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the parameters in the procedure were set to INT instead of DOUBLE

Comment: Oh, so now there's a procedure. I wonder what else you didn't tell us ;-)